# function returning pointer to string not working

Tags: c

I want to know why doesn't the following work correctly? Though I have tried the other ways that work, but for the sake of more clarity I would like to know the problem occurring here.

```
char *fuc(char *s)
{
     char t[10];
     int r=0;
     while(s[r] != '\0')
     {
        t[r] = s[r];
        r++; 
     }
     t[r]='\0';
     return &t[0];   
}

main()
{
    char s[]="abcde";
    char *p;
    p=func(s);
    puts(p);
}
```

Comment: This is at least the 100th question about returning pointers to local variables.

Comment: duplicate so many questions regarding this why don't you make it duplicate no effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `fuc()`, `char t[10];` is a local variable. Once your function finishes execution, there is no existence of `t`. So, in the caller, the returned pointer becomes invalid.

Using that returned pointer further leads to  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to return the pointer from `fuc()`, you need to make use of dynamic memory allocation function , like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family. In that case, inside the caller function, once you're done using the memory, you need to take care for [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)-ing the allocated memory, too.

That said, from the logical point of view, inside your `fuc()`, you're iterating over `t` without any check on the *bounds*. You should check for the size of `t` before using the index.

Furthermore, `main()` is not a proper form of the function. At Least, it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: but if i take      'char *z'      inside func() and put     'z=t'    before while loop and then       'return z;'               then it works..
why does it works in this case??

Comment: @kashish It does not work, it _seems_ to work. Another beauty of UB. Please read the linked content for more info on this. :)

Comment: i got this..thank :)

Answer (score 2):

Array `t` is local to function `func()` so once you exit the function you can't access array `t` which will lead to undefined behavior.

You should allocate memory on heap.

```
char *t = malloc(10);
```

Now you can return a pointer from the function `func()`